# Read multiple DS18B20 temperature sensors faster using Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

[My custom sensor dashboard](https://github.com/nickkraakman/tesla-turbine-telemetry) requests new readings **every second**.

This worked well, until I hooked up 3 DS18B20 temperature sensors (1-wire protocol, so all on 1 pin), which each take 750ms to provide new data.

This is the class I currently use to read the temperature of each sensor:

```
# ds18b20.py
# written by Roger Woollett

import os
import glob
import time


class DS18B20:
    # much of this code is lifted from Adafruit web site
    # This class can be used to access one or more DS18B20 temperature sensors
    # It uses OS supplied drivers and one wire support must be enabled
    # To do this add the line
    # dtoverlay=w1-gpio
    # to the end of /boot/config.txt
    #
    # The DS18B20 has three pins, looking at the flat side with the pins pointing
    # down pin 1 is on the left
    # connect pin 1 to GPIO ground
    # connect pin 2 to GPIO 4 *and* GPIO 3.3V via a 4k8 (4800 ohm) pullup resistor
    # connect pin 3 to GPIO 3.3V
    # You can connect more than one sensor to the same set of pins
    # Only one pullup resistor is required

    def __init__(self):
        # Load required kernel modules
        os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
        os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

        # Find file names for the sensor(s)
        base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
        device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')
        self._num_devices = len(device_folder)
        self._device_file = list()
        i = 0
        while i < self._num_devices:
            self._device_file.append(device_folder[i] + '/w1_slave')
            i += 1


    def _read_temp(self, index):
        # Issue one read to one sensor
        # You should not call this directly

        # First check if this index exists
        if index >= len(self._device_file):
            return False

        f = open(self._device_file[index], 'r')
        data = f.read()
        f.close()
        return data


    def tempC(self, index=0):
        # Call this to get the temperature in degrees C
        # detected by a sensor
        data = self._read_temp(index)
        retries = 0

        # Check for error
        if data == False:
            return None

        while (not "YES" in data) and (retries > 0):
            # Read failed so try again
            time.sleep(0.1)
            #print('Read Failed', retries)
            data = self._read_temp(index)
            retries -= 1

        if (retries == 0) and (not "YES" in data):
            return None

        (discard, sep, reading) = data.partition(' t=')

        if reading == 85000:
            # 85ºC is the boot temperature of the sensor, so ignore that value
            return None

        temperature = float(reading) / 1000.0

        return temperature


    def device_count(self):
        # Call this to see how many sensors have been detected
        return self._num_devices
```

I already tried to return the previous temperature reading if the current one isn't finished yet, however this didn't reduce the time it took to read a sensor, so I guess the only way is to do things asynchronously.

I could reduce the precision to reduce the time it takes per reading, but ideally I would read all of the sensors simultaneously on separate threads.

How can I best implement this? Or are there other ways to improve the reading speed of multiple DS18B20 sensors?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: How are you DS18B20's connected? Are they each on a separate GPIO pin, or are they connected in series on a single pin?

Comment: For this sort of thing, I would typically set up a separate thread (or asyncio task) for reading the sensor values, so that other parts of your code can request temperature values at any time without needing to wait for a sensor read to complete.

Comment: @larsks all sensors connected to a single pin.

Answer (score 1):

You're facing some limitations introduced by the Linux kernel driver. If you were interacting with the OneWire protocol directly, you would only have a single `750ms` read cycle for all three sensors, rather than `(3 * 750ms)`. When speaking the 1-wire protocol directly, you can issue a single "convert temperature" command to all devices on the bus, as described [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/25142/14730), and then read all the sensors.

The Linux driver [explicitly doesn't support this mode of operation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.5/w1/slaves/w1_therm.html):

> If none of the devices are parasite powered it would be possible to convert all the devices at the same time and then go back to read individual sensors. That isn’t currently supported. The driver also doesn’t support reduced precision (which would also reduce the conversion time) when reading values.

That means you're stuck with a 750ms per device read cycle. Your best option is probably placing the sensor reading code in a separate thread, e.g.:

```
import glob
import threading
import time


# Note that we're inheriting from threading.Thread here;
# see https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html
# for more information.
class DS18B20(threading.Thread):
    default_base_dir = "/sys/bus/w1/devices/"

    def __init__(self, base_dir=None):
        super().__init__()
        self._base_dir = base_dir if base_dir else self.default_base_dir
        self.daemon = True
        self.discover()

    def discover(self):
        device_folder = glob.glob(self._base_dir + "28*")
        self._num_devices = len(device_folder)
        self._device_file: list[str] = []
        for i in range(self._num_devices):
            self._device_file.append(device_folder[i] + "/w1_slave")

        self._values: list[float | None] = [None] * self._num_devices
        self._times: list[float] = [0.0] * self._num_devices

    def run(self):
        """Thread entrypoint: read sensors in a loop.

        Calling DS18B20.start() will cause this method to run in
        a separate thread.
        """

        while True:
            for dev in range(self._num_devices):
                self._read_temp(dev)

            # Adjust this value as you see fit, noting that you will never
            # read actual sensor values more often than 750ms * self._num_devices.
            time.sleep(1)

    def _read_temp(self, index):
        for i in range(3):
            with open(self._device_file[index], "r") as f:
                data = f.read()

            if "YES" not in data:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                continue

            disacard, sep, reading = data.partition(" t=")
            temp = float(reading) / 1000.0
            self._values[index] = temp
            self._times[index] = time.time()
            break
        else:
            print(f"failed to read device {index}")

    def tempC(self, index=0):
        return self._values[index]

    def device_count(self):
        """Return the number of discovered devices"""
        return self._num_devices
```

Because this is a thread, you need to `.start()` it first, so your
code would look something like:

```
d = DS18B20()
d.start()
while True:
    for i in range(d.device_count()):
        print(f'dev {i}: {d.tempC(i)}')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

You can call the `tempC` method as often as you want, because it's
just return a value from the `_values` array. The actual update
frequency is controlled by the loop in the `run` method (and the
minimum cycle time imposed by the sensors).

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for this, will test it out as soon as possible! I'm also going to double check the value I used for the pullup resistor, as perhaps that is causing the slower read times somehow.

Comment: No, 750ms is the time it takes to read a full resolution temperature value. See [the datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf) for confirmation.